# Finding DOM element by partial coordinates

Tags: javascript, dom

In JavaScript+DOM, if the mouse event happened on a container, but beneath all enclosed elements, how can I efficiently find the enclosed element that is directly above the cursor (same `x`, different `y`)?

Obviously `getElementFromPoint` does not help me here (even where available), because I am not going to go up pixel by pixel. Finding positions of all elements in container can also be rather slow if there are a lot of elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you use nested HTML tags like this you could bypass the need to use X,Y coordinates and navigate the DOM instead.

```
<ul id="theparent" class="aparent">
  <li id="thechild" class="achild">Something</li>
  <li id="anotherchild" class="achild">Something</li>
</ul>
<ul id="anotherparent" class="aparent>
  <div id="yetanotherchild" class="achild">Something else</li>
</ul>
```

You could use jquery to bind to each `achild` div's onclick event, and then find its immediate parent:

```
$(".achild").bind("click", function() {
  $(this).parent().trigger("childclicked");
});
```

And then you can make something happen for the parent:

```
$(".aparent").bind("childclicked", function() {
  console.log("a child of mine was clicked");
});
```

Comment: Ok, but I need to process click *outside* the child element. Imagine in your example that height of the parent is more than combined height of the children, and there could be more than one child on the same 'line'.

Comment: Do you actually need the X,Y coordinates of the click on the parent element then, or just want an event to be fired? Why don't you just bind to the parent's onclick handler? I think you need to post some HTML and JS to clarify.